# Uploading file using the RestSharp: not working sometimes

Tags: c#, winforms, file, upload, restsharp

I tried to upload a file to the local REST server in C# Winform. When clicking on the the button, nothing happens several times, though. But after a few clicking the button, file is uploaded. I wonder why it works sometimes and why it doesn't work sometimes. I developed it on VS 2010 before, then I moved to  VS 2017.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl + "/upload_file");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + loginUser.Token);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.AddFile("userphoto", 
            filePath, MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(filePath));
        request.AddParameter("username", loginUser.Username);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            MessageBox.Show("The file uploaded!");
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Not updated photo!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the server you are uploading the file to slow to respond or overloaded?  Or is the file large?  Or is your connection slow or low bandwidth?  Have you tried using a web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is going on over the wire?

Comment: Is the value of `loginUser.Token` the same or different when it works vs when it doesn't? When it fails what is the value of `ex.Message`?

Comment: @Brian I haven't tried using a web debugging proxy. I'll tell if I try then, thank you.

Comment: @mjwills I'm sure of logingUser.Token is the same at this situation. When it fails, I get nothing from ex.Message. But I checked the response.StatusCode is "0". when it s going well, the response.StatusCode is "Created". Thanks.